# In which CMakeLists.txt file should I define a target whose sources are in a subdirectory with its own CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project with `src`, `build` and `tests` folders in the root.
The `src` folder looks something like this (simplified)

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── data_generation
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   └── data_generation
│   │       └── main_data_generation.h
│   └── main_data_generation.cc
└── settings
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── constants.cc
    └── include
        └── settings
            └── constants.h
```

`build$ cmake --build .` runs without error.

`main_data_generation.cc` contains a `main` function, and I want to make it executable, so I can run it with the command.

```
./build/data_geneneration/main_data_generation
```

I am guessing that in the CMakeLists.txt I should put `add_executable(data_generation src/main_data_generation.cc)` But into which one?

*src/CMakeLists.txt*

```
add_subdirectory(data_generation)
add_subdirectory(settings)
# more subdirecories...
```

*src/data_generation/CMakeLists.txt*

```
file(GLOB data_generation_SRC
     "*.cc"
)

add_library(data_generation ${data_generation_SRC})

target_include_directories(data_generation PUBLIC include)
```

the CMakeLists.txt file in the root directory

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(MultiplyTest LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

Comment: Have you just tried it? It doesn't matter as long as the path to the cpp file is correct. Pick where it looks cleanest. I'd add it right next to the `add_library` command.

Comment: yes, I added `add_executable(main_data_generation_ main_data_generation.cc)` after `add_library(data_generation ${data_generation_SRC})`. But no executable was generated. At least I can not find it in build/src/data_generation folder

Comment: Take a look in build/bin

Comment: There is no bin folder in build. Build has `CMakeFiles`, `src`, `tests` subfolders

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Open build/CMakeCache.txt. There should be a variable `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` or `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` either of them should point to where the executables are dropped. Also read the output of cmake or re-run with the `-v` flag for verbose output.

Comment: Thanks  
@Friedrich for your help. After`set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin/)` I have now the executable.

Comment: @Friedrich those variables are _optional_ and typically left up to the user who configures the project for building. See my answer.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding the variables would be in CMakeCache.txt even when not set. I would not suggest to set `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` in a CMakeLists.txt. I think that something must have gone wrong with `cmake -S . -B build`. Although I have no clue what and how.

Comment: BTW, [globbing source files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) is discouraged. You may also consider using `target_compile_features` instead of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`.

Answer (score 0):

Things should be workable no matter where you put it. The differences will be in

- how you specify the path to the source file (`src/main_data_generation.cc`), since relative paths for `add_executable` are taken relative to the [current source directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html).
- where the target executable gets put in the build folder (in the [current binary directory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html) at the point where the executable target is defined), unless you do something like override it with [the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` target proeprty](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) or [the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).

If your target is a shared or static library instead of an executable, see the analogously named variables and target properties such as [`ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) and [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).